# Question title doesn't wrap properly

Tags: bug, design

Noticed this weird formatting issue

[image]

Why doesn't the text wrap the whole work 'conventional' properly?

The question title doesn't contain a '-' [Can I increase [ELAN] Trackpoint sensitivity [on my Thinkpad], beyond conventional limits?](https://superuser.com/questions/1743559/can-i-increase-elan-trackpoint-sensitivity-on-my-thinkpad-beyond-convention)

**Edit**

I also see this on different stack sites, e.g. a question I just asked in Photography. `connect` doesn't need to be hyphenated.

[image]

Comment: [why] should it wrap the whole word, rather than splitting on a syllable boundary?

Comment: Why would the title need to be split by a syllable? There's plenty of real estate to not require the title to be hyphenated

Comment: Where did you see the title wrap in this way? I'm seeing the whole word "conventional" on the second line (i.e. not split across 2 lines), both in search results and the [elan] tag page – and in the `/questions` listing as well.

Comment: @V2Blast on the questions list page, when it was on page 1.

Comment: @V2Blast, This was reported 4 years ago too, and claimed to be fixed, here: [On sites with new responsive theme, word wrap on long titles breaks in the middle of a word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318655/282094) - but I still see it, with the addition of a hyphen here: https://superuser.com/